# how to add values to external var in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

i need to create external variable (array) which contain data received from Json object. this data array is going to used to bind combo box.

what i have tried:-

```
var data = [
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'TimeRecord.aspx/ReturnComplexType',
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (arg) {
            alert('hello Inside new');
            for (var i = 0; i < arg.d.length ; i++) {
                "projectCode"=arg.d[i].ProjectCode
                //data.push(arg.d[i].ProjectCode)

            }

        },
        error: function (arg) {
        }
    })
];
```

HTML Code:

```
  <td><select id="Select2" data-bind='options: data, value: selectedProject' style="width: 312px"></select>
```

i tried different approached to assign values to this var variable in for loop. but i couldn't able to bind it. please help.....

**Edit**: my full other code

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.CheckIn = ko.observable();
    this.CheckOut = ko.observable();
    this.Lunch = ko.observable();
    this.projectLine = ko.observableArray([new projectsWorked()]);

    this.TimeForWork = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.CheckIn() ? this.CheckOut() ? parseFloat(this.Lunch()) ? parseFloat(this.CheckOut()) - parseFloat(this.CheckIn()) - parseFloat(this.Lunch()) : parseFloat(this.CheckOut()) - parseFloat(this.CheckIn()) : 0 : 0;
    }, this);

    this.Rest = ko.observable();

    this.RemainHour = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.TimeForWork() ? self.Rest() ? self.WorkOnProject() ? parseFloat(self.TimeForWork()) - parseFloat(self.Rest()) - parseFloat(self.WorkOnProject()) : parseFloat(self.TimeForWork()) - parseFloat(self.Rest()) : parseFloat(self.TimeForWork()) : 0
    }, this);

    this.WorkOnProject = ko.observable();
    this.grandTotal = ko.observable();

    this.AddLine = function () {
        alert('hello Add');
       // alert(this.grandTotal());
        this.calcTotal();
        this.projectLine.push(new projectsWorked());
    };

    this.removeLine = function (line) {
        alert('hello Remove');
        self.projectLine.removeLine;      
    };
};

function projectsWorked() {
    var self = this;
    this.projectEnable = ko.observable(false); 
    this.hours = ko.observable();
    this.selectedProject = ko.observable();

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Where is the call to applybindings? You have to bind the data source to your elements

Answer (score 0):

The data you are filling must be an observableArray. After getting the data you should set it.
In your `ViewModel` you could have that observableArray and the `options` tag must bind to it. You code should look something like this:

In your ViewModel a like like:

```
optionsData = ko.ObservableArray;
...
// later you should make your ajax call and fill optionsData observable
```

and your View must change to bind to optionsData:

```
data-bind='options: optionsData
```

Making global variables to do these binding is not a good solution.